# Can I use js framework in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ember.js, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension it attaches toolbar on to the DOM.

[image]

Now, I am using css selectors in js to find, attach and manipulate elements. If a designer changes any css selector in HTML content, it breaks the entire toolbar. To avoid this we decided to don't use css selectors in js code.

Can I use js frameworks like Ember, Angular or Backbone for this scenario?

Comment: You could also use IDs, classes (unused by the styles), or data-attributes to select the elements.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just include the needed javascript files in the manifest. You can include any framework you want.

```
{
  "name": "Example Extension",

  ...
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    ...
    "js": ["/lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"]
  }]
}
```